# Linking html to css does nothing (ATOM)

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

Im trying to link my css file in the html file but anything ill try doesnt work.

- changing paths
- creating another file/folder
- renaming

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gamerologie</title>
  </head>
```

```
.h1 {
font-size: 300px;
}
```

this title need to change it's color to red but nothing happens

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: nope, no error on browser console. happened this a while ago and now  again

Comment: first of all this css code not affect to color of text it can just font size and h1 tag also having font-size so you should use `!important` and .h1 is define class, head tag h1 not require class definer .(dot)

Comment: sry i have modified this css thing and forgot about it lol

Comment: and btw nothing changed

Comment: are you using a web server? have you tried `href="./css/style.css"`

Comment: yep! ty for the advice . putting " . " before / helped and also putting css h1 without " . " worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but the CSS you are providing isn't supposed to change the font's color, just the size. In addition to that, you are selecting every item whose class is "h1". Only when you remove the dot, you'll be selecting every h1. Hope that helps!